# Kubectl exec -it fails with error: error: unable to upgrade connection: Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes

**Preface:** This is occuring in kubernetes 1.17.2.

About a month ago I renewed all my certificates (as they would expire in 25 days) via

> 'sudo kubeadm alpha certs renew all'

Then I copied the updated /etc/kuberenetes.admin.conf to $HOME/.kube/config.

Everything was fine for 25 days, and then the certificate expiration date arrived, and most things continued to work just fine.  I can create, apply, delete, get logs/describe pods/nodes, drain nodes etc.

But I can no longer

> kubectl exec -it  bash

After looking through what s/o has to offer here are some things I've determined are not the issue:

1. Kubelet client certificates on all worker nodes are correct and unexpired.
2. Control plane services have all been restarted and are running properly (api server, controller-manager, and scheduler)
3. The ca.crt on all workers match what's on the master.

I've also restarted all kubelet services with no effect.

Running exec with the -v=3 flag has a bunch of errors about permission being denied to write to $HOME/.kube/cache/discovery/(ip and port)/things.

I checked, and everything under $HOME/.kube/cache/discovery is owned by root, which I found surprising, but I'm not sure what to expect there.

I'm pretty confident it's related to a certificate expiration, but so far as I can tell, no referenced certicicates are expired.

Here is the output from the exec -it -v command:

```
I0926 09:10:38.207383  143977 cached_discovery.go:130] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/servergroups.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/servergroups.json.951747418: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.218182  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.358037648: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.223832  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apps/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apps/v1/serverresources.json.233202372: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.270628  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.491603985: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.286187  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/v1/serverresources.json.246617561: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.288167  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.050273651: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.290221  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.663074870: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.292567  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.861438680: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.294598  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta2/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta2/serverresources.json.153396170: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.296621  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/extensions/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/extensions/v1beta1/serverresources.json.374028172: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.298626  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.055142558: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.302635  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.349584095: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.304796  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.828927593: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.306933  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/events.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/events.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.749609603: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.309070  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1beta1/serverresources.json.891187629: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.311296  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.095032423: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.313529  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.681854769: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.315781  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/policy/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/policy/v1beta1/serverresources.json.623984267: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.317914  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v1/serverresources.json.105061109: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.319951  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1/serverresources.json.877278959: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.321926  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/node.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to mkdir /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/node.k8s.io/v1beta1: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.324019  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.303121412: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.325963  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.187370454: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.328049  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.531871096: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.330015  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.215681985: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.332101  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta1/serverresources.json.552182828: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.334021  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to mkdir /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.336229  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.897633413: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.338151  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.866995967: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.340325  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.530593673: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.342279  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.523148963: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.344700  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.398974408: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.346887  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.075738247: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.349032  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.925550673: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.351282  143977 cached_discovery.go:78] skipped caching discovery info due to the server is currently unable to handle the request
I0926 09:10:38.351323  143977 shortcut.go:89] Error loading discovery information: unable to retrieve the complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: the server is currently unable to handle the request
I0926 09:10:38.361244  143977 cached_discovery.go:130] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/servergroups.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/servergroups.json.078017807: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.383656  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apps/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apps/v1/serverresources.json.925277627: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.391307  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/v1/serverresources.json.640309234: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.434800  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.467193527: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.436832  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.950885546: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.438719  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta2/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta2/serverresources.json.319412588: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.440611  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.196545918: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.442429  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.098460512: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.444233  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.979104658: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.446167  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/extensions/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/extensions/v1beta1/serverresources.json.167910548: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.448055  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.930787558: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.449955  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authentication.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.931838216: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.451917  143977 cached_discovery.go:78] skipped caching discovery info due to the server is currently unable to handle the request
I0926 09:10:38.453789  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.694079164: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.455842  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.500010219: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.457690  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.018542512: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.459606  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v1/serverresources.json.062236495: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.461493  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.838471257: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.463525  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.157864947: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.466064  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/authorization.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.241774237: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.468064  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.946278103: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.469925  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.481704225: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.472079  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.777763835: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.474016  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/events.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/events.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.236970469: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.476174  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/storage.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.613842783: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.478043  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.335527145: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.480113  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to mkdir /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.482040  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/policy/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/policy/v1beta1/serverresources.json.558002310: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.483961  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/autoscaling/v2beta1/serverresources.json.393956776: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.485988  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/coordination.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.744410394: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.487968  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/networking.k8s.io/v1/serverresources.json.612010332: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.489993  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1/serverresources.json.856159470: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.492015  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/node.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to mkdir /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/node.k8s.io/v1beta1: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.494009  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/batch/v1beta1/serverresources.json.591595375: permission denied
I0926 09:10:38.496019  143977 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to open /home/username/.kube/cache/discovery/ip_port/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json.749766009: permission denied
F0926 09:10:38.522153  143977 helpers.go:114] error: unable to upgrade connection: Unauthorized
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it for helping other community members.

Comment: It hasn't been resolved yet.  I have a maintenance window scheduled in a few weeks when I'm planning on upgrading (kubeadm upgrade --plan etc...) and I'm hoping that resolves it.  If not, apparently I'll just have to reset and reinit the cluster which means a day of downtime for my team.  Bummer.  I'll follow up with the result when I have one.

Comment: My maintenance window finally came, so I thought I'd follow up.  Upgrading the cluster from 1.17.2 to 1.18.17 fixed all my connectivity issues.  So apparently kubeadm alpha certs renew all doesn't actually upgrade all the certs necessary to continue running a stable compute cluster.  But on the good news side - the upgrade was relatively painless!

Comment: Same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74939683/how-to-create-a-pod-and-attach-with-a-terminal-later-on and using k3s v1.25.4+k3s1

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same situation and the master node reboot helped.