# How to create a pod and attach with a terminal later on

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run a multi-container pod, and interactuate with it via a terminal.
With `kubectl run -ti` I can run a monocontainer pod and attach easily to it.

I think I have to `kubectl apply` to create a complex pod, and later *attach* to it.

I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
  kubectl run alpine --image alpine                                                                       pod/alpine created

  kubectl attach -i alpine                                                                                      If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container alpine not found in pod alpine
```

I'm using latest `k3s v1.25.4+k3s1` under a Linux host (Ubuntu 22.04).

Comment: Do you mean you want to interact with a specific container within the pod?

Comment: @RonakJain, that's right

Answer (score 1):

This does work:

```
  kubectl run alpine --image alpine --command sleep -- 999d                                               
pod/alpine created

  kubectl exec -ti alpine -- ash                                                                                
/ #
```

I need an auxiliary `sleep`.

Comment: That would work with any command, including `bash` or any other shell variant, as long as the command does not terminate immediately

Answer (score 0):

You need attach interactively first:

`kubectl run -it alpine --image alpine`

Then detach by using CTRL-P, then CTRL-Q

To reattach, you then use:

`kubectl attach alpine -c alpine -i -t`

Note that if you close the shell at any point, you terminate the pod, and it will restart

Comment: How about if I use `kubectrl apply` in order to launch alpine container?

Comment: `Ctrl+P` and `Ctrl+Q` do nothing in my case.  Maybe it depends on the terminal setup.

Comment: @david.perez that would not work.

Comment: If you are on mac, it'll probably be CMD instead of CTRL

Comment: I'm using Linux and `konsole` as the terminal app.

Comment: The combination is CTRL+P, and then CTRL+Q (it's a two-step shortcut)